# Diagonalising a finite set of infinite sets

Tags: isabelle

I have a finite set of distinct pairs of `'a × 'b set`; I want to obtain choose from each `'b set` a /distinct/ 'b. That is, I want to find out how to define `choices` below such that I can prove the two lemmas:

```
context
  fixes X :: ‹('a × 'b set) set›
  assumes ‹finite X›
  assumes ‹(a, B) ∈ X ⟹ infinite B›
  assumes ‹(a, B⇩1) ∈ X ⟹ (a, B⇩2) ∈ X ⟹ B⇩1 = B⇩2›
begin
  definition choices :: ‹('a × 'b set) set => ('a × 'b) set› where ‹choices X ≡ ?›

  lemma ‹(a, b) ∈ choices X ⟹ ∃B. b ∈ B ∧ (a, B) ∈ X› sorry 
  lemma ‹(a⇩1, b⇩1) ∈ X ⟹ (a⇩2, b⇩2) ∈ X ⟹ a⇩1 ≠ a⇩2 ⟹ b⇩1 ≠ b⇩2› sorry
end
```

As an example, if we knew that ‹X ≡ { (1, {7 <..}), (2, {5 <..}) }›, then example valid values of `choices X` would be `{ (1,8), (2,6) }` or `{ (1,1982), (2, 9) }`.

How do I define `choices`?

Comment: One solution (if sets are really required) is explicitly constructing choices. It is annoying but works. That goes along the lines of defining ``function find_one_mapping :: ‹('a × 'b set) set ⇒ ('a × 'b) set ⇒ ('a × 'b) set› where
  ‹find_one_mapping X' mapping =
     (if X' = {} ∨ ¬finite X' then mapping
     else 
       let (a, b) = SOME x. x ∈ X';
           b' = SOME x. x ∈ b ∧ x ∉ snd ` mapping
       in
        find_one_mapping (X' - {(a, b)})  (mapping ∪ {(a, b')}))›`` and proving properties. Converting the set to a list via SOME anv then doing a similar construction works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathias Fleury has already provided an outline of a plausible solution. I would like to provide a (not necessarily better) variation using inductive predicates. Please note that I relied heavily on `sledgehammer` and, overall, did not make any attempts to think the solution through.

```
definition add :: "'a × 'b ⇒ ('a × 'b) set ⇒ ('a × 'b) set"
  where "add x C = 
    (if fst x ∉ Domain C ∧ snd x ∉ Range C then insert x C else C)"

inductive good_choice :: "('a × 'b set) set ⇒ ('a × 'b) set ⇒ bool"
  for X :: "('a × 'b set) set"
  where 
    "good_choice X {}"
  | "good_choice X C ⟹ (a, B) ∈ X ⟹ b ∈ B ⟹ good_choice X (add (a, b) C)"

definition choices :: "('a × 'b set) set ⇒ ('a × 'b) set"
  where "choices X = (SOME C. good_choice X C ∧ Domain X = Domain C)"

lemma single_valued_add:
  assumes "single_valued C" 
  shows "single_valued (add x C)"
  using assms unfolding add_def single_valued_def by auto

lemma good_choice_single_valued:
  assumes "good_choice X C"
  shows "single_valued C"
  using assms by induction (auto simp: single_valued_add)

lemma good_choice_ab:
  assumes "good_choice X C" and "(a, b) ∈ C"
  shows "∃B. b ∈ B ∧ (a, B) ∈ X"
  using assms
  apply induction
  subgoal by simp
  subgoal by (metis add_def fst_conv insert_iff snd_conv)
  done

lemma good_choice_inj: 
  assumes "good_choice X C" and "(a⇩1, b⇩1) ∈ C" and "(a⇩2, b⇩2) ∈ C" and "a⇩1 ≠ a⇩2" 
  shows "b⇩1 ≠ b⇩2"
  using assms
  apply induction
  subgoal by simp
  subgoal by (metis Range.intros add_def insert_iff prod.inject snd_conv)
  done

lemma good_choice_insert:
  assumes "good_choice X C"
  shows "good_choice (insert x X) C"
  using assms
  apply induct
  subgoal by (simp add: good_choice.intros(1))
  subgoal by (meson good_choice.intros(2) insertI2)
  done

lemma finite_Range:
  assumes "finite (Domain R)" and "single_valued R"
  shows "finite (Range R)"
proof-
  define f where "f x = (THE y. (x, y) ∈ R)" for x  
  have "Range R = f ` (Domain R)"
  proof(intro subset_antisym subsetI)
    fix y assume "y ∈ Range R"
    then obtain x where "(x, y) ∈ R" by auto
    moreover with assms(2)  have "f x = y" unfolding f_def 
      by (simp add: single_valued_def the_equality)
    ultimately show "y ∈ f ` Domain R" by auto
  next
    fix y assume "y ∈ f ` Domain R"
    then obtain x where "x ∈ Domain R" and "y = f x" by auto
    with assms(2) show "y ∈ Range R"
      unfolding f_def by (auto simp: single_valued_def the_equality)
  qed
  with assms(1) show ?thesis by simp
qed

lemma ex_good_choice:
  assumes "finite X"
    and "⋀a B. (a, B) ∈ X ⟹ infinite B"
    and "⋀a B⇩1 B⇩2. (a, B⇩1) ∈ X ⟹ (a, B⇩2) ∈ X ⟹ B⇩1 = B⇩2"
  shows "∃C. good_choice X C ∧ Domain X = Domain C"
  using assms
proof(induction rule: finite_induct)
  case empty then show ?case using good_choice.intros(1) by force
next
  case (insert x F)
  from insert(3,4,5) have "∃C. good_choice F C ∧ Domain F = Domain C" 
    unfolding insert_iff by metis
  then obtain C where gc_C: "good_choice F C" and Dom_eq: "Domain F = Domain C" 
    by clarsimp
  obtain a B where x_def: "x = (a, B)" by force+
  from insert.hyps(2) insert.prems(2) have "a ∉ Domain F"
    unfolding x_def by auto
  with Dom_eq have "a ∉ Domain C" by simp
  have inf_B: "infinite B" using insert.prems(1) unfolding x_def by auto
  from insert have "finite (Domain C)" by (metis Dom_eq finite_Domain)
  moreover from gc_C have "single_valued C" 
    by (auto intro: good_choice_single_valued)
  ultimately have "finite (Range C)" using finite_Range by auto
  then have "B - Range C ≠ {}" by (metis finite.emptyI finite_Diff2 inf_B)
  then obtain b where "b ∈ B - Range C" by auto
  then have "b ∈ B" by simp
  from gc_C have gc_xC: "good_choice (insert x F) C" 
    by (auto intro: good_choice_insert)
  have aB: "(a, B) ∈ insert x F" unfolding x_def by simp
  have "good_choice (insert x F) (add (a, b) C)"
    by (rule good_choice.intros(2)[OF gc_xC aB ‹b ∈ B›]) 
  moreover have "Domain (insert x F) = Domain (add (a, b) C)"
    unfolding x_def
    by 
      (
        metis 
          DiffD2 
          Dom_eq 
          Domain_insert 
          ‹a ∉ Domain F› 
          ‹b ∈ B - Range C› 
          add_def 
          fst_conv 
          snd_conv
      )
  ultimately show 
    "∃C. good_choice (insert x F) C ∧ Domain (insert x F) = Domain C"
    by auto
qed

context
  fixes X :: ‹('a × 'b set) set›
  assumes fin: ‹finite X›
  assumes inf: ‹(a, B) ∈ X ⟹ infinite B›
  assumes sv: ‹(a, B⇩1) ∈ X ⟹ (a, B⇩2) ∈ X ⟹ B⇩1 = B⇩2›
begin

lemma good_choice_choices:
  "good_choice X (choices X)" and "Domain X = Domain (choices X)"
proof-
  from fin inf sv ex_good_choice obtain C 
    where "good_choice X C ∧ Domain X = Domain C"
    by metis
  then have "good_choice X (choices X) ∧ Domain X = Domain (choices X)"
    unfolding choices_def by (rule someI)
  then show "good_choice X (choices X)" and "Domain X = Domain (choices X)"
    by simp_all
qed

lemma choices_ex:
  assumes "(a, b) ∈ choices X"
  shows "∃B. b ∈ B ∧ (a, B) ∈ X"
  using good_choice_ab[OF _ assms] good_choice_choices .

lemma choices_inj: 
  assumes "(a⇩1, b⇩1) ∈ choices X" and "(a⇩2, b⇩2) ∈ choices X" and "a⇩1 ≠ a⇩2" 
  shows "b⇩1 ≠ b⇩2" 
  using good_choice_inj[OF good_choice_choices(1) assms] .

end
```